# Unable to Generate Create or Enable Script

Tags: replication, sql-server-2019

MS SQL Server 2019

I am running into an issue trying to generate create or enable scripts for two of our replication publications.  There is a 3rd publication on this server that the script generation works fine.  We have tried setting File format to International text (unicode) and Windows text (ANSI), both options have been attempted with Append script to file checked and unchecked. We also have tried generating the script to Clipboard, File, and New Query Window.  They all fail with this error:

### "TITLE: Generate SQL Script

SQL Server cannot generate the SQL script.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

---

Heterogeneous queries require the ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS options to be set for the connection. This ensures consistent query semantics. Enable these options and then reissue your query. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 7405)

For help, click: https://docs.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-7405-database-engine-error

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

On both the publications where the create script generation fails we can generate the drop or disable script with no issues.

I have already tried settings ANSI_NULLS and ANSI_WARNINGS to ON and it makes no difference.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a problem with SSMS you are using. What version are you using? What if you try different version (newer/older)?

Comment: I was thinking the same thing.  I started with SSMS 18.6.  I installed 19.2 and still had the same error.